# Manipulate sIFR color with javascript

Tags: javascript, sifr

Is there a way affect the sifr hover color from a javascript event?  I know you can set up sifr to have rollover states and that works fine, but what i'm trying to do is rollover an image and then have the sifr object's hover color show. Is this possible?  I'd prefer not to rebuild the object if that's at all possible. I can't point you to a link b/c it's on my local network.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With sIFR 3 you can use the [FlashInteractor](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/FlashInteractor) object to change the CSS applied to the text.